# Bootstrap: change layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site which reacts to scrolling similar to [this one](http://www.deluxetemplates.net/2014/09/autoworld-blogger-template.html/demo/).

The sidebars fall under the main section's content so to see the left/right bar's content you need to scroll up to the very bottom.

But on [this site](http://www.lordlikely.com/about_likely) when changing size of the page, the sidebars are still on their respective places, so you can scroll to the left/right to see their contents.

Is there a way to make the site behave in the second way, when on desktops?

```
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row row-no-padding">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k3xdfd7/2/)

Comment: Change the `@media` in the css that's related to those sidebars.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `col-xs-4` to the div classes

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
```

Comment: @xort, but isn't the font-size the only thing that changes? I mean, when I run your fiddle, I can always see all the 3 columns, while on the second site when increasing page, the sidebars run out of the view area (to the left and to the right).

Comment: @parsecer I don't think the other website is using Bootstrap and I don't think it's responsive. What this does is ensure that columns take up 4 units each, but in your original code you used `col-md-4` meaning that this class will apply to medium sized devices (992px and up). so the column are reverting back to their default behaviour when smaller than 992px. The `col-xs` classes are in effect when the screen sinze is less than 768px http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid